# Asignar valor variable a estilo css en javascript

Tags: javascript

Esto usando **javascript** para modificar algunos va algunos valores en los estilos, para ello hago unos cálculos, y después asigno ese valor al estilo del identificador que quiero modificar, pero no me muestra ningun tipo de cambio.

```
document.getElementById('barra_logro_mensajes').style.right = mover;
```

Si lo hago manualmente, no hay ningún problema:

```
document.getElementById('barra_logro_mensajes').style.right = "97.6";
```

He probado con comillas simples, dobles, con `\"`, pero nada.

Comment: Disculpa podrias colocar la forma en que estas realizando el calculo para saber si es algo en al forma en que estas obteniendo el valor?

Comment: Y si le añades `px` a tu variable ?  `mover+"px"` dado que un número entero  o flotante solos *(sin unidad de medida)* no son válidos para asignar a dichas propiedades.

Comment: @Dev.Joel No sé cómo no me he dado cuenta. Era eso. Si quieres publica la respuesta en formato respuesta para que pueda validarla. Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está  al Asignar un valor a una propiedad  `css` , le estás enviando un número `(int o float)`  pero sin una unidad de medida `(px , em)` por eso no es reconocido ya que se espera una `cadena`. Para solucionar bastaría con concatenar el valor obtenido por sus cálculos `+ la unidad de medida`

```
var mover = {calculos...}
document.getElementById('barra_logro_mensajes').style.right = mover+ "px";
```